# Using LINQ/Delegates, how to initialize a property belong to all the members of an Object of a type list?

Tags: c#, linq, class, foreach, delegates

This is the scenario:

```
//MyClass in a collection which makes MyObjects a list.
MyObjects = new ObservableCollection<MyClass>();
```

In this case if `MyClass` has a property called `Arm`, per say, how is it possible to initialize `Arm` property of all the members of `MyObjects` without iterating them inside `Foreach` loop like:

```
foreach (var MyObject in MyObjects)
{
    MyObject.Arm = "Manly"; 
}
```

I thought something like code below would be possible, but no

```
MyObjects.Select().Arm = "Manly";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LINQ specifically does not have a "mutate all" method because it's trying to be kind of functional. If you absolutely must have this you can define your own `ForEach` extension method that takes an `Action` and runs it on all items.

```
public static void ForEachAbomination<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Action<T> action) {
    foreach (T item in source)
        action(item);
}
```

This allows you to do

```
someObjects.ForEachAbomination(i => { i.Arm = "Manly"; });
```

But honestly, I think a `foreach` is more readable if you're mutating things.

Comment: Not at all. There isn't a must. Just wanted to learn such thing if possible. Appreciate it :)